# How to access lotus notes client's recent mails using java

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have **IBM notes client 9.0**. I need to **access it's inbox** and read and parse the mails and then send the automatic reply.

So, basically my program required to be a kind of **listener to the mail box** and when ever new mails comes it will **parse it send the response**. How to do it? I have kept Notes.jar in the class path.

I surfed and did not get the enough examples.However I was able to do some stuffs like getting the platform name using **NotesFactory**. Any suggestions and links/documents to examples will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an agent in the mailbox and specify the type as "Before new mail arrives".  This will run as mail is received and let you reroute the mail or change any properties before it reaches the inbox.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097211

Comment: I guess "After mail arrives" would be more appropriate. "before" code is executed by the router and it's preferable not to risk delaying/blocking it. "After" will have some delay though.

Comment: Is this agent need to be written in Lotus script?. Its better if I have a java agent

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you use.